# How to make minus icon disappear using for in loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, icons

When click on save button function myfunc2 will be exceuted which use a for in loop to iterate the minus array. This array conatain all the minus icon. i set style.display = 'none' and expect when i click the save button the icon will disappear, but it didn't work. i dont know what went wrong

```js
const minus = document.getElementsByClassName('minus');
const item = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
const input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
//right
const save_btn = document.getElementById('save');

save_btn.addEventListener('click',myfunc2);
//delete all minus 
function myfunc2() {
    for(let x in minus) {
        minus[x].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.fa {
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.item {
    gap: 10px;
}
a:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--font awe-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--bs-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--js-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container mt-3">
        <h1>Bucket list</h1>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Add item</button>
        <form>
            <!--d-flex overide item-->
            <div class="item d-flex mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control">
                <a href="#" class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item d-flex mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control">
                <a href="#" class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
            </div>
            <div class="item d-flex mb-3">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control">
                <a href="#" class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
                <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success save">Save</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you check your browsers *developer* tools for errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 things you are doing wrong. First of all,

```
const save_btn = document.getElementByClassName('save');
```

should be

```
const save_btn = document.getElementsByClassName('save');
```

Secondly, save_btn would now be an array since you have gotten multiple elements by class name (hence the getElement**s**ByClassName) plural form.

> The getElementsByClassName method of Document interface returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class name(s). ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName))

So calling `save_btn.addEventListener('click',myfunc2);` wouldn't work since you are trying to assign this to an array. You either use

```
save_btn[0].addEventListener('click',myfunc2);
```

or, a more recommended approach, give the button an id and use `getElementById()` ([doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById))

Changed snippet below:

```js
const minus = document.getElementsByClassName('minus');
const item = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
const input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
//right
const save_btn = document.getElementById('saveBtn');

save_btn.addEventListener('click', myfunc2);
//delete all minus 
function myfunc2() {
  [].forEach.call(minus, function(m) {
    m.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.fa {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.item {
  gap: 10px;
}

a:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <!--font awe-->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!--bs-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!--js-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container mt-3">
    <h1>Bucket list</h1>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-3">Add item</button>
    <form>
      <!--d-flex overide item-->
      <div class="item d-flex mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control">
        <a href="#" class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="item d-flex mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control">
        <a href="#" class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="item d-flex mb-3">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control">
        <a href="#" class="minus"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
      </div>
      <button type="button" id="saveBtn" class="btn btn-success save">Save</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Edit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <script src="js.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @M B i tried your solution but both didnt work though:((

Comment: What didn't work? Try combining both my answer and the other answer given by Guille.

Comment: I just edited the code snippet above i change to getElementById and it still not work:((

Comment: @LinhChys Now that you are using an ID, you need to add an id to `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success save">Save</button>`. Right now, you only have a class. After doing that, you have to replace you for loop with what Guille has suggested above.

Comment: I have changed the snippet with the above information

Comment: you code work when i run the code snippet but it doesnt work (icon delete not disappear when click save button) when i copy it in vscode and open with live server (chrome) @M B

Comment: @LinhChys What was the error? Use F12 to open developer tools and look at what message is being output.

Comment: i see no error in console though... @M B

Comment: Try completing the code (submit the form to a valid location) and see if the issue persists. This happens because the code is trying to submit the form to nowhere. If you want a temporary fix while you finish your form, change `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. I have done this change in my snippet.

Comment: @LinhChys Great! Make sure to accept this answer if you found it helpful.

Comment: @M B please tell me how to do it. I google and it said there should be click a check mark beside the answer but i cant see it...